# SMS View Controller does not dismiss itself

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I have a view controller from which I have an action method `sendSMS`, which creates the SMS View Controller... Problem is, when I actually send the message, the controller will not dismiss, or it won't create any logs, so I guess the `didFinishWithResult` method is not even called. Big thanks goes to all of you!

So, my `.m` looks like this:

```
    - (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller animated:(BOOL)animated onComplete:(void (^)(void))callback
{
    MIKEAppDelegate *APP_DELEGATE = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    UIViewController *presentedModalVC = [APP_DELEGATE.window.rootViewController presentedViewController];

    if (presentedModalVC) {
        while (presentedModalVC.presentedViewController) {
        presentedModalVC = presentedModalVC.presentedViewController;
        }
        [presentedModalVC presentViewController:controller animated:animated completion:callback];
    } else {
        [APP_DELEGATE.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:animated completion:callback];
    }
}


-(void)sendSMS
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])

    {
        NSLog(@"SMS composer appeared");

        controller.body = @"Testy Test";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"774252704", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

        [controller presentViewController:controller animated:YES onComplete:nil];
     }
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
             didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Result: SMS sending canceled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Result: SMS sent");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Result: SMS sending failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Result: SMS not sent");
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

EDIT 1:

My `.h` looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController.h>

@interface MIKETableViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
-(void) sendSMS;



@end
```

EDIT 2:

Ok I tried to launch sendSMS method by pressing button, and everything works as it should, so there is a problem in that HOW I call the method. Thing is that I call the method from myCustomTableCell Class... Idea is, when I slide the cell of the screen It will call the sendSMS method. Please see .m file from my custom cell

```
-(void)panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self];

    MIKETableViewController *mainController = [[MIKETableViewController alloc] init];

    //NSLog(@"Panned with translation point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(translation));

    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                 sender.view.center.y);


    CGPoint breakingPoint = CGPointMake(320,sender.view.center.y);
    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(150, sender.view.center.y);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(500, sender.view.center.y);

    if (sender.view.center.x <= startPoint.x) {
    sender.view.center = startPoint;
    }

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (sender.view.center.x >= breakingPoint.x) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             sender.view.center = endPoint;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Bought!");


                             self.timeLabel.text = timeLabelValue;
                             self.priceLabel.text = priceLabelValue;
                             self.infoLabel.text = infoLabelValue;

                             [mainController tableView:mainController.self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:mainController.self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];

                             [mainController sendSMS];
                         }];

        } else {
        //recognizer.view.center = startPoint;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             sender.view.center = startPoint;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Returned!");
                         }];
        }
    }
    [sender setTranslation: CGPointZero inView: self];
}
```

Comment: Why do you override `presentViewController` method ?  IMHO You should not override a method unless and until you have no any other ways.

Comment: So you present a modalVC (the MessageComposer) inside a modalVC?

Comment: Well it supposed to be like that I'm gonna present MessageComposer inside MainViewController. But if I do this, I got an error, that I'm trying to present a view controller inside controller which not exist... (yet)

Answer (score 0):

It should work, But your code looks proper, so most probably you have not conformed the delegate `<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>`

@Janak Nirmal : Sorry, In hurry i didn't see the delegate method implementation.

Put the break point in the delegate method and see whether the control comes to that method.

In sendSMS method use this code to present :

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

now check. and only when send or cancel button pressed, the delegate will be called.

**EDIT**

The problem is because of that method :

```
presentViewController:animated:onComplete:
```

On which controller you present from the same controller you need to dismiss.

For example :

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES onComplete:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:animated completion:callback];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController
dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

**EDIT**

Import this in your .h file

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

Add this header file and check whether the delegate is being called.

**EDIT**

So you are saying that :

```
messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:
```

this delegate method even now is not getting called on clicking send or cancel????

**EDIT**

instead of this line of code

```
[controller presentViewController:controller animated:YES onComplete:nil];
```

put this code and tell me whether the delegate method being called

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]rootViewController];

        [rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**EDIT**

Only way is left out is, give me access to your code somewhere in VCS and i will help you out with the problem.

Comment: OP has written same code. Would you mind showing how your answer is different from his code ?

Comment: Yep, the code is same... I checked, and I have the delegate in .h file... Any more thoughts?

Comment: posted my .h file in the question

Comment: well, in the moment when I send the message or trying to close the controller, xcode shows this error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa17e6f5b)

Comment: with that line of code, the sms view controller won't appear :/

Comment: ok, tried to apply it into my code, but no luck :( Can you please show the answer in my code snippet? Thank You very much

Comment: imported the MessageUI, still does not work, the method is probably not even called...

Comment: exactly... Right now, when I press send, the app is taking some time to send the sms, then it freezes and crashes without stopping on my breakpoint

Comment: didn't help... I guess there is problem with reloading the main controller, but can't find the mistake

Comment: ok I found out, that the problem is with that how I call the method. Please see edited question

Answer (score 0):

You are dismissing self in the mail composer delegate method, instead of the mail view controller, change:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

to

```
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Yeah, that was first mistake... But the controller still doesn't want to dissappear...

Comment: ok, I've put the breakpoint inside the didFinishWithResult method, and it seems, it's not being called. Any ideas?